# Pointers in C, simple doubts

Tags: c, pointers

I'm trying to understand some basic principles of pointers. Someone told me that assigning value to a pointer variable will change the actual variable value. Is that true? I wrote a piece of code and got this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int x=5;
    int *address_of_x = &x;
    int y = *address_of_x;
    *address_of_x = 9;
    printf("The value of x is: %d\n", x);
    printf("The X is at: %p\n", &address_of_x);
    printf("value of y = %d\n", y);
    return 0;
}
```

and got the output like this:

```
The value of x is: 9
The X is at: 0028FF04
value of y = 5
```

why the value of "y" stayed 5? Is that because of the ordering of commands?

Comment: A pointer contains an address.  The address points to a house.  You can copy the address multiple places and that doesn't move the house, and if you erase the address that doesn't destroy the house.

Comment: (But when you use `*` (in a reference, not a declaration) that calls in the carpenters to duplicate the house or modify one house to look like another.)

Comment: In most of the English-speaking world, "doubt" is not synonymous with "question"; the word "doubt" implies disbelief.

Comment: @KeithThompson, I'm sorry..

Comment: @Giri: For what, writing English as you learned it? No need to apologize, I'm just clarifying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`y` isn't a pointer, it is an integer. This line:

```
int y = *address_of_x;
```

basically says "take the value pointed to by `address_of_x` and copy it into `y`.

If you had instead done this:

```
int *y = address_of_x;
```

Then `*y` would be `9`.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is.  `address_of_x` is assigned a pointer to `x`, but `y` is a completely independent `int` variable.  You assign it the same value as `x` (through a pointer), but `x` and `y` are different variables.

At this point, assigning to `*address_of_x` will change the value of `x`, but not `y`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes that was because of the ordering of the commands 
when `int y = *address_of_x;` this executed the 'address_of_x' contained `5` and hence `y` got that value

Answer (score 1):

```
 +--------------+      
 |   5          |
 |*address_of_x |
 +--------------+
        ^
        |         y=*address_of_x =5
        |
 +--------------+
 | address_of_x |
 | 0028FF04     |
 +--------------+
```

**Next time**

```
 *address_of_x = 9

 +--------------+      
 |   9          |
 |*address_of_x |
 +--------------+
        ^
        |         but y still 5
        |
 +--------------+
 | address_of_x |
 | 0028FF04     |
 +--------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You are right. Your pointer pointing to `x` not `y`. After pointer pointing to `x` `*address_of_x` will assigned to `y`. So `y` will get the value of 5.

Try to print value of `x`, It will changed to 9. Because `*address_of_x` pointing to `x`.

```
printf("value of x = %d\n", x); //output = 9
```

Answer (score 0):

Statement

```
int y = *address_of_x;
```

assigns value at `address_of_x` to `y` and then after

```
  *address_of_x = 9;
```

is modifying the variable to which `address_of_x` points to (which is `x` here), not `y`.